# query list with linq lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq

How would I get participants that are in a list of counties?  I get the counties in var counties, then I want to get all of the participants that have a CountyOfParticipationId that is in the list of counties.

```
if (collaborationId != null)
{
    var counties = (from c in db.CountyCollaborations
                    where c.CollaborationId == collaborationId
                    select c).ToList();
    participants = participants.Where(p => p.CountyOfParticipationId in counties);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Where(p => counties.Contains(p.CountyOfParticipationId))`

Now if there's a lot of data be careful with the complexity of this. `Contains` in a list is O(n), so overall the algorithm is O(n*m) with n,m being the # of participants and the # of counties.

For better performance you could store the counties in a HashSet, which has O(1) Contains, meaning O(n) overall.

Of course if the number of counties is small it doesn't matter, really.

**EDIT**: Just noted that your list doesn't contain the ids but full objects. For the code above to work you also need to change your linq query from `select c` to `select c.Id` or something like that (don't know the name of the field).

Answer (score 3):

```
participants = participants
.Where(p => counties.Any(c=> c.CountyId == p.CountyOfParticipationId) )
```

Or

```
participants.Where(p => p.County.CollaborationId == collaborationId)
```

should also work if you have set up relations properly

Comment: @user1202606 Something like the second query will probably be better if you can include it when initially retrieving the participant, rather than retrieving them and then doing a second filter against them.  We can't see that code, but it's possible the linq against participants is using linq2objects instead of linq2entities/sql which will not perform as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better in some situations since you won't have to store counties separately if the linq method is translating the expression to sql behind the scences.

```
participants = (from p in participants 
                  join c in 
                      db.CountyCollaborations
                          .Where(cty=>cty.CollaborationId == collaborationId)
                      on p.CountyOfParticipationId equals c.CountyId
                select p);
```

Comment: It was never specified that sql was in play, but this is a good solution regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each county has a CountyId:

```
participants = participants.Where( p => 
  counties.Select(c=> c.CountyId ).Contains( p.CountyOfParticipationId) );
```